# Tap outside Android dialog to dismiss it?

Tags: java, android, dialog, themes, android-3.0-honeycomb

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow tap outside a popup dialog (or an Activity with a dialog theme), and dismiss it by just tapping outside of it?

I made a quick picture to illustrate it:

[image]

Normally, you have to press the back key to dismiss the dialogs, but on Honeycomb it could be great to have the option of just tapping outside the dialog, due to all the screen estate.

Comment: I believe dismissable is the default behavior - at least for an Activity with a Dialog theme.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

My app is a single activity with Theme.Holo.Dialog. In my case the other answer did not work. It only made the other background apps or the launch screen to receive touch events.

I found that using [dispatchTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) works in my case. I think it is also a simpler solution. Here's some sample code on how to use it to detect taps outside the activity with a Dialog theme:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect dialogBounds = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogBounds);

    if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY())) {
        // Tapped outside so we finish the activity
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: This works better if you change the if condition to `if (!dialogBounds.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()) && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)` That way it doesn't close if the user accidentally moves their finger outside the `Activity`.

Comment: Using API level 8, Using an activity with theme `android:Theme.Dialog` and with this code: `dialogBounds.top` and `dialogBounds.left` have the value 0; and `dialogBounds.bottom` and `dialogBounds.right` have the values of the screen size, suggesting that the diolog window is actually assumed as full screen. So I can't put this code to work. Any other ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 92):

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
```

Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's bounds.

Comment: This is the best solution...So simple. Why isn't this the answer?

Comment: I needed it to work on an Activity with the dialog theme, and this won't work in that case, but I've upvoted it for general dialogs.

Comment: `this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);` works for a Dialog Activity

Comment: No such method in `AlertDialog.Builder`, me not happy.

Comment: Here I posted the complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126701/prevent-dialog-activity-from-interacting-with-background-activity-when-clickin/23128194#23128194

Comment: @Pang for `AlertDialog.Builder` try  `alertBox.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: @Pang @Xylian `SetCanceledOnTouchOutside` is a function that can be called on the AlertDialog returned by `AlertDialog.Builder(activity).Create()` its not not on the builder itself.

Comment: @Pang you can set the AlertDialog.Builder in Dialog reference like :
    Dialog dia = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
and use dia to use SetCanceledOnTouchOutside method

Answer (score 14):

There is a `TouchInterceptor` method which will called when you touch on out side of popup window

For example

```
mWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    mWindow.dismiss();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

`mWindow` is the popup window

And if you want same functionality for Activity you have to follow below steps.

1) Add flag before `setContentView()` method called in `onCreate();`

```
 getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    // ...but notify us that it happened.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
```

2) Override `onTouchEvent()` event in Activity

and write below code

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish", 3000).show();
                finish();               
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The complete copy is here

**Activity**

```
package net.londatiga.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewQuickAction3DActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         // Make us non-modal, so that others can receive touch events.
        getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

        // ...but notify us that it happened.
        getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi", 3000).show();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**This is manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.londatiga.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".NewQuickAction3DActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This is for `PopupWindow` only, right? I'm using a standard Activity with the Theme.Holo.Dialog theme in Honeycomb.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it before you wrote it, but it didn't work either :( Missing a semicolon on finish() btw :)

Comment: Using Theme.Holo.Dialog? Remember, this is Honeycomb.

Comment: If you want to test in small screen just set theme of activity as dialog and click outside it will give you message.

Comment: I'm using a Honeycomb tablet, and I'm starting an activity with Theme.Holo.Dialog from another activity, and pressing outside the activity dialog bounds doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I had test in Honeycomb tablet emulator using  Theme.Holo.Dialog and it is working fine for me

Comment: Did you set the theme in the manifest.xml file? That's where I set it.

Comment: Yeah, that works - but I don't want the background activity to receive touch events. I have some buttons in the background activity that shouldn't be triggered. I guess I could just disable it upon starting the popup intent, but if there's an easier way, I'd definitely prefer that.

Comment: Can you come in chat room "Android Discussion" ?

Comment: @Dharmendra let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2916/discussion-between-michell-bak-and-dharmendra)

Comment: This pretty much work, the problem is when I touch outside I also interact with the UI elements of the activity below which is bad.

Answer (score 6):

You may use

```
  dialog.setCancelable(true\false);
```

For the lastest vesrions of Android;

It will disable outSideTouching event.

Comment: It is tested for all versions except KITKAT :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Activity#setFinishOnTouchOutside](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setFinishOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29) too, if your dialog is an `Activity`. That's gotta be the shortest way for `Activity`s ;)

(It's API 11+ though. But API <= 10 is generally screen size normal.)

Comment: This is the winning answer, the question is addressing Activities themed as Dialogs, not Dialogs.

Answer (score 4):

```
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(
            android.R.color.transparent);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Check if you have this line of code or not....

```
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply I write dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); and it work for me, window will not dismiss on outside tap .

Answer (score 2):

this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

you can use this

Comment: For dismiss use the `true` value: `this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);` This method is needed for the _dialog activity_ but not for pure _dialog_.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but yet another solution:

1. Make your foreground activity full-screen. Usenested layouts: The full-screen layout should have transparent background (e.g. `@null` or `@android:color/transparent`). The inner layout should have a visible background.
2. Add an `OnClickListener` to the invisible outer layout that `finish()`es your activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use style of dialog rather than other styles.

For example, Use

```
public YourCustomDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_dialog_NoActionBar);
}
```

When you use other styles like **Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar** , the dialog will not be dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Any views within the dialog can set to consume the touch event so that below won't be called.

```
onCreate(){
    getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutParams lp=dialogp.getWindow().getAttributes(); 
lp.flags=LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
```

I added this and it works flawlessly on 3.0 up, but should work on all.