# Cancel Dialogfragment click outside

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialogfragment, which should dismiss, if i click outside of the dialog. I have no button or something else to close the dialog.

But before the dismiss is calling, I want to check a field in my dialog. If the check is positive, then the dialog should close, else not.

Which method can I override to do that? Or can I do it manual with a onTouchListener, which dismiss the dialog, if I'm clicking beside?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214365/tap-outside-android-dialog-to-dismiss-it

Answer (score -1):

I would do following. I would add transparent button on background of your dialog fragment in order to fragment take all place and set onClickListener for that button. Maybe it's wierd but it's work ))