# Event Tap outside Android dialog?

Tags: android

I have a dialog which I am using to input data into my app.  I want to catch the event touch outside of my dialog. I want to check the value before the input is made to SQLite. How can I do this?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7789137/3419997)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setCanceledOnTouchOutside (boolean)` to listen for touch outside but your dialog should be cancelable on touch outside to do implement this. or else you can create a fragment dialog with transparent background and on the layout of your dialog manually set the part that is visible for the users. This will allow you to implement click listeners for the dialog.